# get binary int, java

Tags: java, variables, binary

I want to pull an int from a getMethod() that is in binary format. Does anyone know how to use: `int i = 0b10101010;`(taken from a previous post on Stack Overflow thank you all) with a variable.
`int i = 0bgetMethod();` does not work in any of the multiple ways I have tried it (0b + var, etc). I do not have the actual value, so I cannot hard code the 1's & 0's.
Any help would be appreciated. This is for an assembler, this binary number is selecting the register in the register file, passed in string format to preserve it until I parse it.

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: like tnw says, show your code. If you are referencing another SO question please provide the link.

Answer (score 1):

A digital computer stores all `int`(s) in binary (even those you encode in decimal). You can use [`Integer.toBinaryString(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString-int-) to see the binary representation of any `int`.

If you need to *parse* a binary `String`, you can use [`Integer.parseInt(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-) where the first argument is the `String` to be parsed and second argument is a radix (for binary that would be `2`).

Answer (score 0):

code: int i = Integer.parseInt(Micro.RegSel, 2);  produces an error(the method is not applicable for enumbody).
Micro.RegSel is an enum implements enumbody  that results in a string of 4 1's & 0's. If I simply print it, it prints out dropping all the leading zeros. I need the leading zeros. My code needs a total of 32bits, and this is part of it.
one of the switch statements has: Micro.RegSel.setFourBit("0011"); This will print "11". printing the string directly from the enum:    0011

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(Micro.RegSel.getFourBit().toString(), 2); produces a java.lang.NumberFormatException even though Micro.RegSel.getFourBit().toString() prints all 4 digits
```

After trying several options (that's where I asked my question) and reading the stack trace, I realized that the problem was the default was "xxxx" for the opcodes that do not select a register.
so I rewrote it like this:
                int i = 0;
        String j = Micro.RegSel.getFourBit().toString();
        if(j.matches("[\d]")){
        i = Integer.parseInt(j, 2); 
        }
It works like I need it to. Thanks